# google analytics page uri link repeating the domain

Tags: google-analytics

In my Content Drilldown, when I go to the second page path level of one of my domains the link that displays duplicates the domain in the uri.

For example..

If I have the following:

```
events.company.com/
```

When I drill down the link above I will get:

```
/http:/
/
/some-directory/
```

When I click the Page dimension I will then get these links:

```
events.company.com/
events.company.com/http://events.company.com/index.php#
events.company.com/http://events.company.com/index.php#view/all
```

So you'll see that the links above like below is incorrect:

```
events.company.com/http://events.company.com/index.php#
```

It needs to be

```
events.company.com/index.php#
```

....but I don't why it's coming through like that and how to correct it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: That's nothing GA would do by itself. Go to the view settings and check if there are misconfigured filters (something that works on the Request URI field). Else check your tracking code if you pass a virtual page path to yoour tracking calls.

Comment: I looked through the settings and I see under the Filters section an "Add Hostname" filter with the following: Field A -> Extract A with Hostname is (.*) and Field B -> Extract B with Request URI is (.*) and Output To -> Constructor with Request URI is $A1$B1 Do you think it's this filter that is causing this?

Comment: I guess so. I't looks like somebody wanted to add the hostname to the page path and picked the wrong field (Request URI is the Url complete with http etc. - I think the correct field in the GA backend is simply called page). Removing or correcting the filter will help with future data, but everything already collected is messed up and cannot be repaired.

Comment: Ah ha..I gotcha. So "Field B" is producing the full "http:///path" and it's being appended to Field A which is the hostname...Makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, seems like someone followed the "right" instructions from GA help:

> By default, the data in your reports includes only the Request URI and
>   not the domain name:
>
> ```
> URL of page: http://www.example.com/foldername/page.html
> Request URI: /foldername/page.html
> Domain name: www.example.com
> ```
>
> If you'd like to see the domain name as well as the Request URI in
>   your reports, create an Advanced filter for your view with the
>   following settings:
>
> ```
> Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
> Field A: Hostname
> Extract A: (.*)
> Field B: Request URI
> Extract B: (.*)
> Output To: Request URI
> Constructor: $A1$B1
> ```
>
> Note that creating URL rewrite filters like the one described above
>   can affect Analytics' ability to match your goals properly.
>
> If you're using Analytics filters to rewrite your URLs, you need to
>   make sure that your goal settings reflect these changes. Like all
>   filters, URL-rewrite filters are applied to the raw data coming into
>   your account, before goals are processed. As a result, your goal and
>   funnel URLs should reflect the final, rewritten format of the URL.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en

However, it does messes data quite a lot. I believe this is an issue with GA, at least this documentation is misleading. Such filter also affects URL matching on Goals and funnels, so I would not recommend it.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)